# How to filter array in react native?

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting, arraylist, filtering

I found some solutions but not exactly what I want. I want to get all array from object name where condition I will explain by the following example for if array=

```js
let array = [{
  "mobile1": [{
     "screensize": "6.5"
  }]
},
{
  "mobile2": [{
    "screensize": "6.5"
  },
  { 
    "price": "2000"
  }]
}]
```

i want all array from mobile2 then final output will be

```js
let final = [{
  "screensize": "6.5"
},
{
  "price": "2000"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter method: [Array.prototype.filter() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const filterData = abc.filter(item => item.mobile2 )[0].mobile2
```